# PySide/PyQt not loading system styles on Linux when installed via Pip

Tags: python, linux, pip, pyqt, pyside

I am writing a GUI application on Linux. I am using virtualenvs in development, where I install required packages using Pip (with Poetry). When I install PyQt6 (or PySide6; I have tried both and both have the same problem) my application cannot find any system theme.

```
>>> PyQt6.QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.keys()
['Windows', 'Fusion']

>>> PySide6.QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.keys()
['Windows', 'Fusion']
```

In practice, without specifying a style, my application loads the Fusion theme (which I think looks ugly and out-of-place).

I have tried installing Qt6 via `apt`, and it still doesn't work. I read that installing PyQt5/PySide2 via `apt` apparently fixed this problem for Python-base Qt5 applications, but PyQt6 and PySide6 aren't available via `apt` at the time of writing. Moreover, I would like to use the Pip package as it makes package management much simpler.

Does anyone know how I could make PySide6 load, for example, the Ubuntu Adwaita theme?

Comment: Linux doesn't have a "system style" by definition (it depends on the desktop manager), and except for the basic ones ("fusion" and "windows") Qt doesn't ship anything else by default, nor it should, since any window manager has its own styling system. If you want a more consistent look with your system, you need to look for Qt compatibility themes to be installed on your distro; there should be something like "adwaita-qt".

Comment: I installed adwaita-qt using apt, but it doesn't show regardless.

Comment: Maybe it's adwaita-qt6?

Comment: Does the virtual-env installation have a it's own copy of qt6? Look in e.g. *venvdir/lib/python3.x/site-packages/PyQt6/Qt/lib*.

Comment: @musicamante I can't find a package under that name.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yup, the Qt library is installed in the PySide6/PyQt6 directory in the virtual environment.

Comment: So that explains why the system styles aren't available: the local copy doesn't look for them in the right places. By default, it will look in the application executable directory (which will be the same as for Python), and the *local* Qt6 installation plugins directory (which will be within the venvdir). However, if you have system plugins that were built for a compatible version of Qt6, it should still be possible to load them. See the various options outlined in the Qt6 docs: [The Plugin Directory](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/deployment-plugins.html#the-plugin-directory).